# Get the address of a cell under condition formula in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

For eg:

```
Sheets("GNPA"). Range (TopCell, BottomCell). Value = "=IF ('NPA-SUMMARY'! R1C1 =""NPA AS ON ""& R [-1]C,'NPA-SUMMARY'!" & x & ","""")"
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context - perhaps some sample data?

Comment: Where in the string you show the required address should be? I cannot understand only looking to your pseudo code. At least, copy the formula as it exists (you want it) on the cell...

Comment: Set x = Sheets("NPA-SUMMARY").Range("W2").End(xlDown) - using for different sheet ("NPA-SUMMARY")

Comment: I used this way to transfer value ('NPA-SUMMARY'!" & x & " ) but system is saying user defined error

Comment: Set x = Sheets("NPA-SUMMARY").Range("W2").End(xlDown) used to get the address from another sheet

Comment: When I putted this one " & x & " I got the value but address is not getting

Comment: 'NPA-SUMMARY'!" & x & " I tried this one but error message is coming

Comment: Then, use `Sheets("NPA-SUMMARY").Range("W2").End(xlDown).Address`...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I used x variable set as currency and used to get the address of a cell in another sheet named (NPA-SUMMARY) .Put the code as                                                                   Set x = Sheets("NPA-SUMMARY").Range("W2").End(xlDown) and tried to get the address using if condition , Sheets("GNPA"). Range (TopCell, BottomCell). Value = "=IF ('NPA-SUMMARY'! R1C1 =""NPA AS ON ""& R [-1]C,'NPA-SUMMARY'!" & x & ","""")" But when I use error is showing

Comment: Then, use Sheets("NPA-SUMMARY").Range("W2").End(xlDown).Address  -   It is not working, the same error message is showing. Please remember that I am using inside the IF statements.